# как добавить любую строку двумерного массива в одномерный массив и вывести

Tags: java

```
 package helloworld;

 import java.util.Scanner;

 public class arrow {


 public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
    
    int i,j,x = 0, n = 5;
    
    int[][] arr = new int[5][5];
    int ar[] = new int[5];
    
    for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        for (j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++){
            arr[i][j] = (int) (Math.random()* 19 + 1);
            if (i == 4){
                ar[i * n + j] = arr[i][j]; 
            }
        }
    }
    
    for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        for (j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++)
            System.out.print(arr[i][j] + " ");
        System.out.println();
    }
    
    for (i = 0; i < ar.length; i++)
        System.out.print(ar[i] + " ");
    }  
}
```

Comment: во первых, массив имеет фиксированную длину, то есть добавить в него нельзя, можно только что то записать в уже имеющееся место. Во вторых - если у вас массив чисел, то записать в него можно только числа. То есть в массив чисел нельзя записать двумерный массив, так как двумерный массив не является числом.

Answer (score 0):

Не совсем понимаю, что вам надо. Ну допустим.
Есть двумерный массив

```
int[][] array =
{{1, 2, 3}
{4, 5, 6}
{7, 8, 9}}
```

Чтобы получить строку из этого массива, надо сделать вот так: `int[] str = array[0];`

Чтобы получить столбец:

```
int columnNum = 0;
int length = array[columnNum].length;
int[] column = new int[length];
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    column[i] = array[columnNum][i];
}
```

В этих примерах я создаю новые массивы для того, чтобы поместить туда кусок из двумерного массива. Добавить кусок в уже существующий массив вы скорее всего не сможете, потому что длина любого массива фиксирована и задаётся при создании.

Comment: Спасибо большое кое то понял